Notification sound is stops when pulled down the notification bar
I set a custom sound for Flutter local notifications. It works fine, but when the notification bar is pulled down, the sound stops. I want the sound to continue even when the notification bar is pulled down.
Here is the code I tried.
     const int insistentFlag = 4;

        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
          1,
          'Adhan Sound',
          '',
          tz.TZDateTime.from(scheduledTime, tz.local),
         NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                'adhan channel id', 'adhan channel name',
                channelDescription: 'adhan channel description',
                importance: Importance.max,
                priority: Priority.high,              
                audioAttributesUsage: AudioAttributesUsage.alarm,
                additionalFlags: Int32List.fromList(<int>[insistentFlag]),
                sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(soundFile)),
            iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(sound: '$soundFile.aiff'),
          ),
          androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.alarmClock,
          uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
              UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
          matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
          
        );

There are many questions related to this issue on the internet, but nothing works.
